# Object is not an ADODB Record set = C# filling datatable

Tags: c#, sql, string, ms-access, int

I am trying to bring back records from my access DB by matching the number selected in my comboBox2 and bring back all the rows in relation to that number - this has worked fine in other projects but for some reason I keep getting the related error above - any help would be nice.. the error is on the dap.Fill(dt, typeof(Int32)); - When I take "typeof int32 out" I get this error: "SYNTAX ERROR MISSING OPERATOR IN EXPRESSIONS 'OCR = ';"

EDIT: if it makes a difference I am using this code in this type of event:

EDIT FIXED WIH HELP FROM ALL COMMENTS - FIXED CODE NOW ADDED AFTER CODE THAT DIDNT WORK

**comboBox2_SelectedValueChanged**

```
   string strprovider = @"provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\farrejos\Documents\inboxV2.mdb;persist security info=false";
            OleDbConnection newConn = new OleDbConnection(strprovider);
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from ocr where OCR = " + comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() + "", newConn);

            if (dap != null)
            {
                //dap.Fill(ds);

                dap.Fill(dt, typeof(Int32));
            }

            //dap.Fill(ds, "ocr");

            foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                textBox3.Text = myRow[4].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = myRow[6].ToString();
            }
        }
```

FIXED CODE:

```
  System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select *  from ocr where [OCR] = " + comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() + "", newConn);

        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            textBox3.Text = myRow[4].ToString();

            textBox4.Text = myRow[6].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: not sure what the trailing double quotes are for after the `combobox.selectedtext`?  and you dont need the `tostring` either.  Also are you saying it was the lack of square brackets (ie. it didn't know what was a field or a table) that was the cause? As that's not what the error message suggested at all.

Comment: I really am not sure - I also moved a few other things around like I moved my function event from "valuechanged" to "valuecommited". Not really a useful topic but I will try and provide more information when I get back on that project. (im working on another one for the rest of today).

Comment: that makes more sense, the error was telling you that your SQL was incorrect, and in fact it was telling you that comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() was either null or ''.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
 string strprovider = @"provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\farrejos\Documents\inboxV2.mdb;persist security info=false";
        OleDbConnection newConn = new OleDbConnection(strprovider);
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from ocr where OCR = " + comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() + "", newConn);

        if (dap != null)
        {                
            dap.Fill(ds);
        }

        foreach (DataRow myRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            textBox3.Text = myRow[4].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = myRow[6].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can't use foreach on variable type .datatable

Comment: This error comes back now - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'OCR ='. and if I put ' ' before and after the "" on my sql statement it brings back data type mismatch - not sure if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

If your OCR field is a string field, you might need to enclose your ComboBox value with apostrophes:

```
OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from ocr where OCR = '" + comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() + "'", newConn);
```

**EDIT**

I have not done it in a few years, but I believe to remember that the OleDbDataAdapter gave me some troubles occasionally when using it with a `where` clause in the constructor.

Try it with an `OleDbCommand` instead?

```
            OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            dap.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("Select * from ocr where OCR = " + comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() + "", newConn);
            dap.Fill(dt, typeof(Int32));
```

**Edit 2**

Your SQL statement uses "ocr" as both table name and field name. Possibly this is an ambigiouty the provider has troubles with?

Change it to:

```
Select * from [ocr] where [ocr].[OCR] = ...
```

Some more ideas, try it out in the following order:

- Instead of `*` list the field names you want to select manually
- Enclose table name with `[ ]` brackets
- Enclose field names with `[ ]` brackets
- Rewrite your code to use `OleDbParameter` for your queries.

In any way, I strongly suggest to use **[parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx)** anyway. This will help you to get syntactical problems straight as well as it helps you to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: it's an INT and I've tried this previously anyway :)

Comment: @JoshF91: I edited my post and added a new idea. There is some dark shadow over my memory when last time working with `OleDbDataAdapter`, but I believe there some issues. Have a try with the new code sample.

Comment: @JoshF91: Addde some mor ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start to break down your code, firstly as its complaining about the SQL expression I would move it to its own variable.

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    string sql = String.Format("select * from [ocr] where [ocr].[OCR] = {0}", comboBox2.SelectedText);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

    OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, newConn);
```

Then in the output window you'll see the SQL it tried to execute which should help you narrow down the root cause.